# How to color all menu icons white?

Tags: big-sur

How can I color all icons consistently white?

In the below example you see two programs that show black icons.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s up to app developers to update their menu bar items for Big Sur.

Previously, white text on the menu bar was only used in dark mode, but Big Sur uses the wallpaper to choose the foreground colour of the menu bar. App developers need to update their apps to correctly determine the foreground colour to use in Big Sur.